# I need the events to be a list of javascript objects for a specific day

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need the events to be a list of javascript objects for a specific day. https://25live.collegenet.com/stanford/# Search "old union" on location and you get the list. I need the script to do this search automatically without user input.

any one help me how can i do that.
**Thanks**

Comment: where is your code,what have you tried?

Comment: i can not understand what i do for that

Comment: best and safest bet will be to hire someone to do it for you

Comment: can you do that..

Comment: i can do that but it will cost you :)

Comment: how much you want for me

Comment: hard to tell at this moment